# How to remove "Input method" submenu selection from StyledText context menu?

Tags: swt

I'm using StyledText widget in my SWT app. SWT by default appends "Input method" submenu to the end of existing context menu. Is there any way to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

```
textBox.addListener(SWT.MenuDetect, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event event) 
    {
        StyledText s = (StyledText)event.widget;

        Menu menu = new Menu (s.getShell(), SWT.POP_UP);

        MenuItem item = new MenuItem (menu, SWT.PUSH);
        item.setText("Click here");

        s.setMenu(menu);
        menu.setVisible(true);          
        event.doit = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can ask the `StyledText` for its `Menu` (`getMenu()`), find the correct item (`getItem(int)`) and call `dispose()` on the item. That will delete it from the menu.

Comment: "Input Method" is not among the returned items.

Comment: Linux, Debian Lenny.
I'm using a SWT port, so it could be the ported code. I commented out createIMMenu call for now.

Comment: I thought it was connected to IME somehow. I'm just puzzled how you can see the menu when `getItem()` doesn't return it. Consider reporting a bug against SWT.